# Matrix and quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $$G := \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} \ast & \ast \\ 0 & \ast \end{bmatrix} \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}) \right\}$$
and
$$H := \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} \ast & \ast \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \in GL_2(\mathbb{R})\right\} \subset G$$
What is $G/H$?

My attempt is first, to check whether $H$ is normal and indeed it is. But now to find the quotient group do we just do regular matrix multiplication?

Comment: Wait, what?  Do you mean $G := \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix} \middle| a, b, d \in k, ad \neq 0\right\}$ as a subgroup of $GL_2(k)$?  As you have it now it looks like $G$ and $H$ are matrices...

Comment: Reading this again I guess that's what you must mean.  Do you know the definition of a quotient group?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: Yes, you are right. I have edited the question. Sorry

Comment: Do you know the definition of a quotient group?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: Yes, it is just the coset $gH$ such that $g\in G$ but each such g will be a matrix. Hence, my attempt was to do matrix multiplication

Comment: Okay, so do you have an idea what the cosets are?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: Yes, their union should give us $G$

Comment: I meant, by playing around and calculating particular cosets, do you have a guess as to what each coset is?

Comment: Hint: Try to make $H$ the kernel of a homomorphism into a group you know well (note that $H$ consists of those elements in $G$ where a certain thing is $1$, which might give you an idea how to do this).